# Install Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-office

Can anyone here help me how can I install outlook 2013 with ubuntu 17.10?

Can't find the exact thread here for my question.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-microsoft-office-in-linux/

Answer (score 2):

From my experience Microsoft Office 2007 works normally on Wine since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (now EOL).

According to [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31) MSO 2013 installs normally. You can consult these pages for detailed steps for installation.

The first step is installation of Wine or PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're intent on using the desktop version rather than the Office 365 online version.

To my knowledge Wine is still broken with MS office, so your choice is something like CodeWeavers.

https://www.codeweavers.com/products/#cxlinux/

The reason for this is that Windows applications must be emulated to run in Linux when there is no suitable Linux version. Keep in mind there will likely be some distinct differences and possible bugs with Outlook (or Office in general) on Linux while running in emulation.